# Using fields to complete an API call (Dark Sky Forecast API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

so I've been fooling around with the Dark Sky Forecast API and I was able to get the weather of my own location be displayed onto a webpage. However I hard coded the longitude and latitude and I wanted to take it one stop further and let the user input their own. This is where it stopped working.

Before my code was simply just

```
                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                //Waits until document is ready to run
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    //Beginning of code
                    //Makes the request
                    $.ajax({
                    url : "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/MyKey/1111,-1111+?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,alerts,flags",
                    dataType : "jsonp",
                    success : function(parsed_json) {
                    var location = parsed_json['timezone'];
                    var temp_f = parsed_json['currently']['temperature'];
                    var complete = ("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
                    $('#random').html("<h1>" + complete + "</h1>")
                    }
                    });
                    }
                });

                </script>

                    $('#search').click(getInfo);
                });

                </script>
```

And then I created some HTML fields (I used bootstrap just to keep things tidy) like this

```
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                        <input id="long" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Longitude" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                        <input id="lat" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Latitude" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
                    </div>

                    <div class="rand">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" id="search">Find my location and temperature!</button>
                    </div>
```

And I updated my script to look like this

```
                     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                //Waits until document is ready to run
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    //Beginning of code

                    var getInfo = function(){
                        //Grabs the longitude and latitude
                        var Longitude = $('#long').val();
                        var Latitude = $('#lat').val();
                        //Makes the request
                        $.ajax({
                        url : "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/mykey/" + Longitude + ","+ Latitude + "+?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,alerts,flags",
                        dataType : "jsonp",
                        success : function(parsed_json) {
                        var location = parsed_json['timezone'];
                        var temp_f = parsed_json['currently']['temperature'];
                        var complete = ("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
                        $('#random').html("<h1>" + complete + "</h1>")
                        }
                        });
                    }

                    $('#search').click(getInfo);
                });
```

However at this point it just doesn't work. I click my button and nothing happens. Maybe I did something wrong in the HTML portion because I barely made any changes to the script so I'm guessing that's not the problem.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, figured it out. I did everything right and I accidentally put a plus sign in the url... oops.